# Android Livedata Observer Coroutine Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, kotlin-coroutines

Is it possible to have a co-routine inside an observer to update the UI?

For Example:

```
Viewmodel.data.observer(this, Observer{ coroutinescope })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run any code you want from the `Observer` callback. But it would not be a good idea to launch a coroutine that updates the UI later, because when the coroutine is complete, the UI might be destroyed, which can cause exceptions to be thrown and crash your app.

Just run the UI update code directly from the `Observer`callback.

```
viewModel.data.observe(this, Observer {
    // Update the UI here directly
})
```

That way you know that UI is alive when you update it, since `LiveData` takes the lifecycle of `this` into account.

If you want to launch some coroutine at the same time as the callback, it would be better to do it within your `viewModel` using `viewModelScope`.

```
// This triggers the above code
data.value = "foo"

// Now also launch a network request with a coroutine
viewModelScope.launch { 
    val moreData = api.doNetworkRequest()
    // Set the result in another LiveData
    otherLiveData.value = moreData
}
```

Note that you must add a dependency to `build.gradle` in order to use `viewModelScope`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0'
}
```

Comment: What if we want the coroutine to finish and LiveData deliver results - before we perform any other action on the UI?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it's possible. You can launch a GlobalScope coroutine and when you need update the UI you should be that in activity!!.runOnUiThread

Here a sample.

```
viewModel.phoneNumber.observe(this, Observer { phoneNumber ->
        GlobalScope.launch {
            delay(1000L) //Wait a moment (1 Second)
            activity!!.runOnUiThread {
                binding.textviewPhoneLabel.edittextName.setText(phoneNumber)
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak in disguise to me

Comment: it is not, that is so efficient @EpicPandaForce, it is just a bad practice, but, if he need that, he should use it

Comment: No, it is a memory leak. GlobalScope will run regardless of enclosing Activity and not be cancelled when Activity is dead, so `activity!!` can explode if you navigate back up to 1sec after phone number changes